# Can we get IP address in an MVC Ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC & looking at a method that is used in two instances in a controller. It is used to get the client's IP address.

`GetData` is triggered by an Ajax call from the front end. 
`GetIpAddress` works fine in the `Index` method, but will it work inside `GetData` as it is a standalone method.

```
public class CommonController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
     string ip = GetIpAddress(Request);
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult GetData()
  {
     string ip = GetIpAddress(Request);
  }
}



public static string GetIpAddress(HttpRequestBase request)
        {
            if (request != null)
            {

                string ipAddress = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
                {
                    ipAddress = request.UserHostAddress;
                }
                ipAddress = ipAddress.Split(',').First();
                return ipAddress;
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
```

Comment: I personally use Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"] or Request.UserHostAddress. It works fine with ajax.

Comment: A clients IP address has not be usefull as a Session ID since the idea of classes was replaced by Network masks (1993). And at least from me, it looks like that is what you are trying to do - using the IP adress as a Session ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every standalone method you can access:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
// or 
HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress
```

there fore you can also use

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
// or
HttpContext.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
```

So one example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    string ip = HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress;
}
```